# How to let windows to restart a .net service on failure

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, .net-6.0, application-restart

I am writing a windows service. Unfortunately, I am forced to use a library with a bug. When this bug appears I cannot get rid of it by other means than restarting the process. It is not enough to wrap all code in main function in a loop. I think that I need to either somehow unload and reload the external native library or let the Windows restart the service automatically on failure.

I tried configuring the service as follows:

```
sc failure "MyService" reset= 30 actions= restart/5000
```

This sometimes works. I can see that Windows is able to restart the service over and over.
Unfortunately it depends on how the service crashes in c# code and in some cases does not restart the service. This is the code in c# I am using:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);

builder.Services.AddHostedService(provider => new MyHostedService());

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
WebApplication app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

My observation is the following: If an uncaught exception is thrown in MyHostedService before first await, then `app.Run()` also throws an exception and Windows correctly restart the service as I want.

However, if MyHostedService works for a moment and awaits something several times then an exception occurs then `app.Run()` just returns and Windows do not restart the service.

This is logged to EventViewer:

> The HostOptions.BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior is configured to StopHost. A BackgroundService has thrown an unhandled exception, and the IHost instance is stopping. To avoid this behavior, configure this to Ignore; however the BackgroundService will not be restarted.

I tried throwing or returning non-zero from Main right after `app.Run()` but it does not have any effect.

I also considered changing the value of HostOptions.BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior. But the other possibility is to Ignore the error which I don't want.

The strange behavior of the external library just needs restarting the process which does not work for me. Thank you very much in advance how to modify the code the way that windows restart the service on failure.

Comment: add around every command a try catch and let it write the error into the event log.now you can determine which command actaully fails and the exact cause, and the find the means to end the program clean

Comment: Consider using `NativeLibrary` which allows you to load and unload native DLLs at will.

Comment: @nbk I want which line fails. It is my line which looks like this `throw new Exception("I want windows to restart the service");`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-8-0).

> To correctly allow the service to be restarted, you can call
> Environment.Exit with a non-zero exit code.

However the answer is still not very much satisfying. Even though an error has occured I would prefer to shutdown as much services and call as much Dispose methotds as I could. I would prefer the IHost.Run() to stop cleanly and return non-zero from main.
This seems not to be possible. `Environment.Exit(1)` needs to be called from a hosted service which unfortunately must not be exited cleanly.